# Why django uses "ModelName.objects" to all model related function

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Why django uses ModelName.objects to call all related function? There is no any other way to call these using only ModelName.

To get all posts we use
Post.objects.all()

Comment: [Django automatically assigns a manager to Model.objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/) is there some other functionality that you would like?

Comment: You can use the [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/db/models/query/#QuerySet) class directly if you'd like?

Comment: It does not, `objects` is the name of an object manager, but you can create different managers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Django uses [*managers* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/). Managers can be used to filter the collection of objects, to annotate these, etc. If you do not specify a manager yourself, Django will add a manager named `objects` to your model.

A Django model has however extra managers: the [**`._default_manager`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#django.db.models.Model._default_manager) and the [**`._base_manager`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#django.db.models.Model._base_manager). Especially the `_base_manager` is interesting, since most of Django's internals use that manager. The reason is that *not* all models have a `.objects` manager.

We can for example define a model with a field that specifies if the object is "deleted". We thus do not really delete the record from the database, but perform a "*soft kill*": we set a status field such that these records do not show up.

We can implement that as:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(db_index=True, default=False)
```

Now we can define two object managers on this `MyModel`: an `all_objects`, and `active_objects`. The `active_objects` will filter on the `is_deleted` field, like:

```
from django.db import models

class ActiveManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset(is_deleted=False)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(db_index=True, default=False)

    active_objects = models.ActiveManager()
    all_objects = models.Manager()
```

If we now access `MyModel.active_objects.all()`, we will thus retrieve all active objects (with `is_deleted` set to `False`). Furthermore `MyModel` will *not* contain an `.objects` manager anymore.

Managers are therefore useful to automatically filter, annotate, prefetch related models, and defer fields with large content without the programmer having to worry much about these tasks.